# Distributed File's and named filegroups in SQL Server performance

Tags: sql-server, hardware, filegroup

I have 2 options when creating a database and the number 1 priority for these databases is performance.

- **Option 1**: Distributed Files over multiple drives on 1 Filegroup. Therefore all files are managed by SQL server and the Hard-Drives are therefore used and managed from a space perspective but we as DBA's have zero control about which drive the tables (And all associated indexes) are stored on.
- **Option 2**: Named File Groups with the database actively partitioned into the specified hard drives.

A good assumption for this question is that all our disks are identical in speed and performance and our SAN controller is of enough quality to not be our bottleneck in this scenario.

Also assumed is that we have a "Good" tempDB setup where we have the correct file partitions on a local SSD to the server.

The second option gives us control and we can put indexes for large tables on different hard disks. This controls our read and write process for high intensity tasks and allows us to read from 2 disks and write to a third.

So my question here is how does the Distributed Files (SQL Managed) perform against the Named File Groups where the disk read and write is the limiting factor in the hardware configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**For Option 1:**

Depending on the SAN vendor, there are many different techniques used to construct a logical disk partition (LUN) for use by SQL Server, and some of them, such as concatenating disks rather than striping.

You should consider database  storage  availability: RAID 1 ( mirroring) , RAID 5 to provide redundancy and RAID 10 and thus improve  disk  availability.

Also SSD disks are manged by SAN and modern SAN Storage auto move files with high access to SSD without user interruption.

Also the cache size of San for Read/Write data should be considered.

So Understand the capability of your SAN and be in touch with SAN engineer to build the data ,log and tempdb files  especially there are different varieties of high/low speed disks contained in SAN.
For more detail [SAN Storage Best Practices for SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-server-san-best-practices/)

[High Performance Storage Systems for SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/high-performance-storage-systems-for-sql-server/)

**For option 2,**

It doesn't matter in SAN environment. For details read:

[SQL Server Database File Groups on a SAN: Relevant or Not?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77323/sql-server-database-file-groups-on-a-san-relevant-or-not)